# Change texture of POD object

Tags: objective-c, cocos3d

Ive just gotten started with cocos3d and I'm making a basic card game. I've already got the model with textures, but I don't know how to specify what texture to use for a given object, or node.  I've got the textured model loaded and rendering using the basic cocos3d template.  Here's my setup code:

```
//Init
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
{
    cardNodes[i] = [CC3PODResourceNode nodeFromFile: @"Card.pod"];
    [self addChild:cardNodes[i]];
    cardNodes[i].location = cc3v ( ( i - 2)*7.5, 0, 0);
    cardNodes[i].rotation = cc3v ( 0,-90,180);
}

-(void) startGame
{
    srand(0);

    //Draw 5 random cards
    unsigned int cards[5] = {0};
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
    {
        unsigned int card = ( rand() % 52 ) + 1;
        for ( int other = i-1; other >= 0; --other )
        {
            if ( cards[other] == card )
            {
                card = ( rand() % 52 ) + 1;
                other = i-1;
            }
        }
        cards[i] = card;
        //Set texture of card node[i] somehow here?
    }
}
```

So how can I change what texture is being used so I don't have to create a new pod file for each card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeatedly loading a POD file does not create multiple copies within memory. That is because the underlying `CC3PODResource` is cached (on purpose), so you'll end up referencing the same model in each of your array elements.

Instead, you should load the card POD once and then create copies of it using the standard `copy` method. This is an efficient copy. It copies configurable properties, but reuses the same underlying mesh vertices. You can then position, color and texture the card copies individually.

To assign a texture to an individual card, simply use the `texture` property.

`CC3DemoMashUp` contains lots of examples of assigning textures to models, and of making many copies of a single mesh node. For instance, try pressing the grid button when running the demo.

Comment: there does not appear to be a `texture` property on the `CC3PODResourceNode`

Comment: Also once I can find the `texture` property, how do I load the actual image into the texture object and assign it?

Comment: The `texture` property is on the `CC3Node` class, which is a parent of `CC3PODResourceNode`. But unless you want to set the same texture for all the nodes in your POD, you should retrieve the individual `CC3MeshNodes` from your `CC3PODResourceNode` using `getMeshNodeNamed:` and set the `texture` property there. You can load textures using the `CC3Texture textureFromFile:` method, or others. As I mention, review the `CC3DemoMashUpScene` implementation. It includes code examples of almost all **Cocos3D** features, including everything I've mentioned here.

Comment: For further clarification, the `texture` property is on the `CC3MeshNode`, otherwise this answer is correct

Comment: Just to clarify your clarification :^), as I mentioned, the `texture` property is defined and implemented on the parent `CC3Node` class, where it propagates to all descendant nodes, setting the same texture on all of them. It is *also* defined on the `CC3MeshNode` subclass, because it is on `CC3MeshNodes` that the texture actually has effect. Many node properties  (eg- texture, colors, toggles, etc) behave this way. Although they take effect on `CC3MeshNode` instances, they are defined on `CC3Node` so that they can be used to change the characteristics of whole assemblies of descendant nodes.

Comment: Well by going to the definition, and also trying to use autocomplete, I was unable to find a `texture` property until I accessed it from the `CC3MeshNode`